# var some = []['forEach']['constructor'];

Tags: javascript, arrays

Im not able to understand this peice of javascript code please can anyone help me understand this.

```
var some = []['forEach']['constructor'];
```

Comment: It's using bracket notation.

Comment: it gets the constructor of [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Answer (score 1):

It is the same as `[].forEach.constructor` what is basically the same as `Array.prototype.forEach.constructor`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to break it down:

```js
[]['forEach']['constructor'];

// Convert bracket property access notation to dot notation
[].forEach.constructor;

// `forEach` is a property of Array.prototype
Array.prototype.forEach.constructor;

// `forEach` is a function reference with a 
// `constructor` property, due to `Function.prototype`
Function.prototype.constructor;

// `Constructor.prototype.constructor === Constructor`, generally
Function;


console.log(
  []['forEach']['constructor'] === Function //=> true
);
```

If you're asking why this code would be useful, I'm not quite sure. Possibly obfuscation.